# Dynamically Created Select Control

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Using Angular's reactive forms I am dynamically creating forms from schemas on my server.  For the UI I'm using Material 2.

In my actual code the formGroup and controls are created from the schema, but in the examples below I just assigned everything for simplicity and to avoid any timing issues.  Currently, I'm using the latest version 2.0.0 beta12.

Everything was working fine until I added the select component.  When I create a 'select' dynamically I'm receiving a template parse error:

```
Can't bind to 'name' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-select'.
```

[Here is a stripped down example of things working fine with basic inputs.](https://plnkr.co/edit/OycgOhALrDQ4Hn5YcsD3?p=preview)

[Here is the same example switched to contain a 'select' control in the form generator.](https://plnkr.co/edit/PJxdB7CGfRyfKM48R6eX?p=preview)  This throws the error.

Here is the html template:

```html
<form>
  
  <div *ngFor="let control of controls;"
    [ngSwitch]="schema.properties[control].element">
    
    <mat-form-field *ngSwitchCase="'select'">
      
      <mat-select 
        [formControlName]="control"
        [(ngModel)]="formValues[control]" 
        [title]="control" [name]="control"
        [placeholder]="schema.properties[control].title">
        
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of schema.properties[control].options" [value]="option.value">
          {{option.viewValue}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

  </div>
  <p> Selected value: {{formValues.select}} </p>
</form>
```

Here is the TypeScript for my view component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'select-form-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-form-example.html',
})
export class SelectFormExample {
  selectedValue: string;

formRoot : FormGroup = new FormGroup({
  select: new FormControl(null)
})

formValues : any = {};

controls: any = [
  'select'
];

schema: any = {
  properties: {

    select: { 
      title: 'This is the display title',
      element: 'select',
      options: [
        {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
        {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
        {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
      ]
    }
  }
 };
}
```

I'm not sure I'm understanding the error.  The 'name' attribute shouldn't need to be an explicit @Input of the control any more than the 'title' attribute should.

I've looked at the component source and name isn't an @Input on matInput and yet this code works for it.  I've looked at roughly related "Can't bind to 'x' since it isn't a known property of 'y'" but none seem to apply here as the 'name' attribute shouldn't need to be an @Input.

Comment: You are required to post your code or markup here, not a third party site which can change or disappear helping no one in the future: [mcve]

Comment: Sorry!  I'll add the code here as well.  I thought it was more helpful to link to the working example.  My fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case my main mistake was mixing Reactive Form syntax and Template form syntax.  For those still learning Angular 2+ like me, this is bad :)

The reason 'name' was allowed on previous iterations of my formGenerator was [ngModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) allows allows the name attribute.  Once I added the 'formControlName' reactive syntax ngModel was ignored per its selector:

```
'[ngModel]:not([formControlName]):not([formControl])'
```

Getting rid of all the 'ngModel's and 'name's in my template did the trick.  So it looks like:

```
     <mat-select 
       [formControlName]="control"
       [title]="control"
       [placeholder]="schema.properties[control].title">
```